# How to flip the lines of a visual selection in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to take a visual selection and flip it so that the first line of the selection is on the bottom. From:

```
<other_stuff>
The
wheels
go
round.
<more_stuff>
```

Visual select the sentence and then flip:

```
<other_stuff>
round.
go
wheels
The
<more_stuff>
```

How to do this simply? I would rather not have to install a plugin to do it.

Comment: Related: [Reverse selected text @ Vim Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_selected_text)

Comment: Duplicate on [SU]: [How to reverse selected lines order in vim?](http://superuser.com/q/189947/269404)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you make a visual selection Vim automatically makes the bookmarks `'<` and `'>` at the start and end of the block respectively, so you can do what you want in a couple of ways.

In normal mode:  `'>dd'<P`

As an ex command:  `:'>d | '<-1 put`

NB the bookmarks remain after you exit visual mode, so you do not have to stay in visual mode to use these.

**edit**:

Oops, I misread the question and thought you only wanted the last line put at the start, but you want the entire block reversed.  The simplest solution if you are on a unix system:

```
:'<,'>!tac
```

This pipes the lines through the unix 'reverse cat' program - tac, part of [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tac-invocation.html).

Comment: Or `tail -r` on OS X.

Comment: Great! There are situations in which a `!` saves a lot of time!

Answer (score 5):

According to `:help 12.4` you can mark the first line with the `mt`, move to the last line you want reversed then use the command `:'t+1,.g/^/m 't`

Comment: Be sure to mark the last line you do *not* want moved; not the first line you do want moved.

Answer (score 5):

For those more comfortable with **Visual Mode**:
 1. Identify the line number above the selection you want flipped using `:set nu`.
 2. Use `Shift-V` to highlight selection you want flipped (visual mode).
 3. `:g/^/m <Line number from step 1>`.

Note that in visual mode it will automatically show up as
    `:'<,'>g/^/m <Line number>` when you type in the command from 3.

This command works by moving the selection one line at a time into the line number that you give it. When the second item gets pushed into the line number given, it pushes the first down to line number + 1. Then the third pushes the first and second down and so on until the entire list has been pushed into the single line number resulting in a reverse ordered list.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Dave Kirby's answer and addressing the "how to do this simply" requirement, you could create a shortcut in your `.vimrc` file. The following example maps the `F5` key to this shortcut:

`map <F5> :'<,'>!tail -r<CR>`

or for OS X:

`map <F5> :'<,'>!tac<CR>`