# How to reverse the order of line fragments within a visual block in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to reverse the order of line fragments selected within a Visual *Block* in vim.  That is, starting from

```
one   = [33];
two   = [22];
three = [11];
```

I would like to get,

```
one   = [11];
two   = [22];
three = [33];
```

by selecting the block of

```
         33
         22
         11
```

and reversing the line order only within this block.

Can this be achieved?  I tried using `!tac`, as described in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561249/how-to-flip-the-lines-of-a-visual-selection-in-vim), but that reversed entire lines, not just the selected block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a plugin called "vis" that tries to do exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/vim-scripts/vis

After installing it, you can select the columns in visual mode and execute `:B sort` to sort just that area.

As an unfortunate side effect, I seem to be getting extra spacing around the selection:

```
one   = [ 11 ];
two   = [ 22 ];
three = [ 33 ];
```

This might be some oddity in my own Vim config, or it might be a general issue. I'd suggest you try the plugin and see for yourself.

Comment: Must be something specific to my own config then. Thank you for checking.

Answer (score 1):

Using [vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) plugin we can do the following: Place the cursor over the first number and type `cxi[` then `2j.`

I am giving this plugin based solution because I think "vim-exchange" it is a more common plugin, specially after those very famous vim screencasts.

Comment: +1, but I'm afraid this solution is somewhat specific to the three-line visual selection case.  If I added `four = [ 00 ];` at the end, it would become much more cumbersome to use---never mind if there were a dozen lines to work with!

Comment: @TedPudlik yes, the solution it is very specific to two or three lines.